# What does VTC mean?

Tags: support, terminology

I've been reading many times the term VTC from this question ([Can there be a draw in League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182306/can-there-be-a-draw-in-league-of-legends/)) and each time I try to find the meaning, the results aren't what I'm looking for or doesn't make sense to me.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VTC is shorthand people commonly use to say "Vote to Close".